# How to select the image icon by jQuery in this condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I let the user create images and buttons (a button with image above it)by clicking on a button: "new_a_window" so I use `append()` in jQuery. But the question is that I have to get the different image as the user press on it.

As the user click the "new_a_window" button, jQuery will create a button with a image in a jDialog(story_pages).

```
$( '#new_a_window').bind('click',function(){
 $('#story_pages').append('<div><button value=window_value
 style="width:100px; height:100px" >

 <img id=window_value src="../pic/white.png" width="100px" height="100px"> 
 </button></div>');
 window_value= window_value+1; //I give each of the images a unique integer value since of 
                               // the value is the index of a image array. 
 })
```

I have to implement the scenario:

As the user presses on the image button, I can get the image's id value.
However, after appending the code snippet above, each image's value is "window_value", 
I can't select it by value. How can I do?

Comment: An image element does not have a value attribute, that's meant for form elements not images.

Comment: @adeneo  All right, then if I change the image value to id? And how
can I achieve my goal? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('#story_pages').append('<div><button value=window_value
 style="width:100px; height:100px" >

 <img value="'+window_value+'" src="../pic/white.png" width="100px" height="100px"> 
 </button></div>');
```

Issue is that you were simple setting the value to a string 'window_value' not the value inside a variable.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

ID should never be a number, if you wish to use id you will need to add text before it.

```
'<img id="window'+window_value+'" src="'
```

to select either one you could possibly do.

`$('#window1')` for id's or i believe `$('img[value="1"]')` would work with values 
(not 100% as value is not a standard attribute)

Comment: UPDATE to image id= '~', since image has no attribute value...Sorry.
But how can I select the image I want?

Comment: look at your syntax of your code you notice window value is a string not a variable like mine is... the coloring gives a good hint :)

Comment: @AbstrcatChaos        $('#window1')? Does "window1" mean "the string " : window + the variable number?

Comment: @Stallman  I assumed you would be getting windows statically in which case use `$('#window'+window_value)`

Comment: @AbstrcatChaos        Uh... I'm trying it.

Comment: Still debugging. It seems that there are still some unknown errors.

Comment: @Stallman if you create a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) as an example i may be able to help further :)

Comment: @AbstarctChaos    
Do you think this is feasible? 
<div><button value=window_value onclick="TO GET THIS BUTTON's window_value "></button></div>
How can I GET THIS BUTTON's value?  The key word would be?('this' won't work.)

Comment: Why would you not simply use `$(document).on('click','button',function(){});`

Comment: [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it filters the even to only button elements... google could have told you that btw

Comment: Thank u...I'm totally new to jQuery... By the way, as I alert the variable window_value, it only display "window_value". How can I let it show the content of the variable?  And what's the key word of "  '+window_value+'   ", I'll search it with Google.

Comment: @Stallman use alert(window_value); no quotes as you want the variable. If this answers your question please remember to mark it as such.. helps me and will help if you wish to ask further questions :)

Comment: No problem! You have helped me a lot, and these information does really help whether I'm still addressing the issue. 
But I'll delay to finish the issue since I need more people's information.
By the way, can you tell me what's the keyword of " '+window_value+' "?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14471/discussion-between-abstractchaos-and-stallman)

Comment: Sorry, it's already 01:00 a.m. here so I went to sleep...
I'll find another chance to talk with you.